# The accident "to" somebody or the accident "of" somebody?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, prepositions

Which sentence is correct? Or are both or neither correct?

1. The accident **to** my child was traumatic.
2. The accident **of** my child was traumatic.

Maybe the first one is correct as in English we say an injury *to* the knee, much damage *to* the house, amputation *to* her fingers, and so on.

Comment: It depends on what you want to emphasize. Do you mean that the accident was generally dramatic? Then you would probably say "My child's accident was dramatic". Or do you mean that someone experienced the accident as particularly traumatic?

Comment: It's *amputation **of** [some body part]*, not ***to***. We wouldn't normally use the Saxon genitive to refer to ***her leg's amputation***, but it's not grammatically "incorrect" to do so.